# C++ variable redefinition

Tags: c++, variables, redefinition

I have a file:

variableinclude.h

```
#ifndef _variableinclude_h_
#define _variableinclude_h_

AClass* variable1;
int* variable2;

#endif
```

But I include this file in another two different ones:

```
- atest1.h

- atest2.h
```

The problem is the following: variable redefinition.

How to avoid that???

Comment: you are getting linker error or a compiler error?

Comment: Note that the include guard is illegally using a reserved prefix (`_v`). Also, by convention macro's are uppercase.

Comment: @MSalters: Why is this reserved? I thought only double underscores shouldn't be used.

Comment: @ur: Double underscores are reserved everywhere in tokens, not just as a prefix. And they're reserved for unspecified use by the implementation. E.g. a compiler may internally define `_variableinclude_h_` as soon as you `#include <variableinclude.h>`.

Comment: Any identifier containing a double underscore is reserved. Anything starting with underscore followed by a capital letter is reserved. Anything else starting with underscore is reserved if it is declared at namespace scope (which your include guard is)

Answer (score 10):

EDIT2:

Welcome to [ODR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule)

EDIT 1:

Make the variables extern in the header file.

```
extern AClass* variable1;   // assuming AClass is declared at this point.
extern int* variable2;
```

Define them once and only once in any cpp file e.g. in main.cpp at namespace scope.

```
AClass* variable1 = NULL;   // assuming AClass is declared at this point.
int* variable2 = NULL;
```